# How do I use Multispec for Landsat data?

Tags: imagery, classification, landsat

It seems that I only can use the Clustering if I want to cluster only one band data..
If I open up more than 1 band (in one image), the cluster toolbar is disabled?

optional:
Is there any free Satellite Imagery processing tools other than this?